# How to create a stub for BusinessException which extends Exception class

Tags: java, exception, mockito

I am trying to create stub for the exception class to return some string , but its not returning that string value.Got error

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<ServiceException> but was<java.lang.NullPointerException>
```

Here is sample code I use

```
BusinessException mockBusinessException =mock(BusinessException.class);

@Test(expected = ServiceException.class)
    public void testValidateForRegistrationError() throws ServiceException, BusinessException{
        when(ChecksUtil.initiateValidation(any(Request.class), any(Content.class))).thenThrow(BusinessException.class);
        when(mockBusinessException.getMessage()).thenReturn("Error");
        facadeBeanTest.createRegistration(RegistrationFacadeMock.getCreateRegistrationRequest());
    }

BusinessException extends Exception
```

Testable class

```
public class FacadeBean{
    createRegistration(){
        try{
        }catch (BusinessException e) {
            String err = e.getMessage(); -- Failed in this line(null pointer exception)
            if(err.contains("Error") ){
                throw new ServiceException(ServiceErrorConstants.CATALOG_NAME, err);            
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Is there any thing missing in that ?could some one suggest.

Comment: Why are you mocking an Exception? Why wouldn't a real BusinessException work?

Comment: I am mocking only BusinessException mockBusinessException =mock(BusinessException.class);

Comment: Are you using PowerMock at all? It looks like you're trying to mock static methods.

Comment: I can use powermockito, thing here is not a statis class : public class BusinessException extends LPBusinessException {}

Comment: its not a static method   public java.lang.String getMessage();

Comment: I'm suspecting that the source of your error is `ChecksUtil.initiateValidation`.

Comment: That line is executed without error, only in the actual test call stubbed value not returned

Comment: I just updated calling class

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException`. That means you tried to reference an object, but your reference is null. Check the line where the exception is thrown and find the error in the code you are testing. My guess is the exception does not have a message and it fails on `err.contains("DMV")`.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the line is "executed without error"; Mockito is not perfect at throwing an exception exactly where the problem is. Mockito has a sense of internal state, and I believe your mistakes have corrupted it. Last question: why do you use `thenThrow(BusinessException.class)` instead of `thenThrow(mockBusinessException)`?

Comment: its resolved after doing like this when(ChecksUtil.initiateValidation(any(Request.class), any(Content.class))).thenThrow(new BusinessException("Error"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in the comments:

> Why are you mocking an Exception? Why wouldn't a real BusinessException work?

and

> Why do you use `thenThrow(BusinessException.class)` instead of `thenThrow(mockBusinessException)`?

Comment from OP, *user3123934*:

> its resolved after doing like this when(ChecksUtil.initiateValidation(any(Request.class), any(Content.class))).thenThrow(new BusinessException("Error"));

---

When there are few dependencies and a reliable implementation, it often makes sense to use *real objects* instead of mocks. If you do use mocks, ensure that your system under test will use the mock instances when necessary, by supplying them in a constructor, mock, or overridden method.